Implementing Burst mode with Kotlin Jetpack Compose
I successfully implemented burst mode in camera , where it captures 30 photos at once.
But the speed of image capture is slow , like it capture 30 images in 13 sec and also while capturing images the camera will pause , i need to capture all 30 images in 3 sec How can i do it.
I am using CameraX api for this implementation.
val imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
        .setCaptureMode(CAPTURE_MODE_ZERO_SHUTTER_LAG)
        .setZslDisabled(false)
        .setTargetRotation(ROTATION_0)
        .setFlashMode(if(torchState) FLASH_MODE_ON else FLASH_MODE_OFF)
        .build()

above is image capture variable , also i used CAPTURE_MODE_ZERO_SHUTTER_LAG to reduce latency
val callbacks = mutableListOf<ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback>()

val vibesList = remember {
   mutableStateListOf<Bitmap>()
}

fun takeBurstVibes(
        imageCapture: ImageCapture,
        context: Context,
    ) {
        
        repeat(30) {
            callbacks.add(object : ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
                override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy) {
                    super.onCaptureSuccess(image)
                    photosTaken++
                    vibesList.add(image.toBitmap())
                    image.close()
                }

                override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                    super.onError(exception)
                    Log.e("Camera", "Couldn't take photo: ", exception)
                    photosTaken = 0
                }
            })
        }

        coroutineScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                callbacks.forEach { callback ->
                    imageCapture.takePicture(
                        ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context),
                        callback
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }


Above code is a function which captures 30images , even i  used coroutines for faster but it is not happening
for (i in if (isCapturing) "capturing" else "capture") {
    Text(
         text = i.toString(),
         fontFamily = FontFamily(listOf(Font(R.font.damion))),
         fontSize = 28.sp,
         fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
         color = Color(0xFF000000),
         modifier = Modifier
         .clickable(
         indication = null,
              interactionSource = interactionSource
         ) {
            isCapturing = true
            takeBurstVibes(imageCapture, context)
         },
   )
}

Can any one solve this and one thing if i hold the capture button it start taking and if i release the button it should stop taking images and increase the speed of image capturing like 3 sec.

So after each image capture callback is triggered and in the callback you're doing image.toBitmap() which might take some time to run.

Then I have to pass the image as image proxy and later to convert it to bitmap, right. Other than this is there any way to make faster.
